# Declutter project configuration files?

Tags: javascript, next.js, configuration

I used a boilerplate nextjs project that produces many configuration files:

```
.env.example
.eslintrc.js
.gitignore
.npmrc
.prettierignore
.prettierrc.js
commitlint.config.js
jest.config.js
jest.setup.js
next-env.d.ts
next-sitemap.config.js
next.config.js
package.json
postcss.config.js
tailwind.config.js
tsconfig.json
vercel.json
```

Is there a way to move them into a separate directory so they won't clutter my project's root dir?

Comment: You could move some of those configurations into `package.json` rather than have a file for each of them (e.g. Jest, ESLint, Prettier, PostCSS).

Comment: @juliomalves how would you do that?

Comment: Look into each package's documentation on how to do it. For instance, this is the Jest one: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration (see `package.json` section).

Comment: Jest doesn't work as I apparently need some nextjs JavaScript to get jest running with nextjs. Any other files you see that I should try?